# ExoPlayer ffmpeg failed to Build library

Tags: android-studio, ffmpeg, android-ndk, exoplayer2.x, android-ffmpeg

I recently tried add extensions in ExoPlayer like ffmpeg extension to support more audio formats in my app, i followed the extension-ffmpeg Readme.md and i successfully created the library for arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a, x86 and x86_64 and inside of these folders are libavcodec.so, libavutil.so and libswresample.so, After successfully creating the library i need to build the aar to include it in my app but when i run

```
cd "${FFMPEG_EXT_PATH}" && \
${NDK_PATH}/ndk-build APP_ABI="armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a x86 x86_64" -j4
```

i get this error

```
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-16 is higher than android:minSdkVersion 1 in ./AndroidManifest.xml. NDK binaries will *not* be compatible with devices older than android-16. See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/user/common_problems.md for more information.    
Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: ./jni/Android.mk    
/home/oni/Android/Sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/build/core/add-application.mk:88: *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
```

I'm a newbie to this and i have tried to see some examples of Android.mk for exoplayer ffmpeg extensions but i did no find anything and i'm stuck in this part, i'm still searching for some examples that might help me to successful build the extension ffmpeg aar.

Comment: Ffmpeg extension now uses cmake to build instead of the ndk-build, that's because the file has been removed on the latests pull requests.

Comment: thanks, i did fix it